# AVRO Generated pojo's + Kafka + Spring Cloud Schema Registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I am considering using schema's to validate data on my kafka topics. I am exploring **spring cloud schema registry** in combination with apache kafka.

If I have understood correctly after reading the docs. Spring cloud schema registry supports avro schema's only ! In avro pojos need to be generated using **.avsc** files on the classpath and that there is a maven plugin which does the needful.

**Problem:**

What if I have custom validations on my pojos's like this ? I would not like generated this pojo in my kafka consumer using avro schema as then I loose my validations. Did anyone come across similar issues ? If so how did you resolve it ?

```
public class Pojo implements Serializable {

 @Color
 private String colour;
 .....
```

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = ColorValidator.class)
public @interface Color {
 .....
```

```
public class ColorValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Color, String> {
......
```

Comment: Not understanding the question... `implements Serializable` is not an Avro type. You don't "need" AVSC files. You can use `@AvroReflect` annotation

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for your time. Actually class Pojo that you see above is how I have defined my pojo's currently in my project. I use custom serdes for serialization and deserialization. Now from this state, I would like to move to schema registry (spring not confluent) but still have the possibility to use ConstraintValidator .

Comment: The schema registry implementation doesn't matter. You're just generating and using local Avro types

Answer (score 0):

> What if I have custom validations on my pojos

You can still define `ConstraintValidator` implementations if you generate POJOs from schema files.

In other words, you make the AVSC, and use the `avro-maven-plugin` to create the classes (`mvn compile`), and then the classpath will have the classes available to define the constraint validators.

You might want to look at the `CustomEncoding` class for actually validating Avro objects, though.

Comment: thanks again for your time. So basically generated classes can be modified, in my case with some extra validation constraints. I would give it a try.

Comment: Incorrect. Generated sources will get overridden each time you `mvn clean compile`